# why is the account generator and quiz self sabotaging when pieced together

Tags: python-2.7

```
import time
import csv
import sys

print("Welcome...")
welcome = raw_input("Do you have an acount? y/n")
if welcome == "y":
        with open("user.csv",'r') as file:
            username=raw_input("Enter username")
            password=raw_input("Enter password")
            fileReader=csv.reader(file)
            for row in fileReader:
                if username==row[0] and password==row[1] and points==row[2]:
                    print("access granted")
                    return username
               else print("denied"):
                       login()


elif welcome == "n":
        username=raw_input("Enter username")
        password=raw_input("Enter password")
        with open("user.csv",'a') as file:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(file)
            csv_writer.writerow([username, password])
            print("access granted")
            return username
else:
    print("Ur stupid")
    sys.exit()




login()

import random
songsfile = open("songs.txt","r")
allsongs = songsfile.readlines() 

def quiz():
    tries = 2
    points = 0
    songnum = [1,3,5,7,9]
    print('An artist and the 1st letter of a song gets outputted')
    print('Get it wrong twice and game over...')
    print('1st guess = 3 points\n2nd guess = 1 point\n')
    while tries > 0:
        artist = random.choice(songnum)
        song = str(allsongs[artist - 1])
        print ('Artist: ' + allsongs[artist])
        print ('Song: ' + song[0])
        guess = raw_input('Input your guess: ')
        if guess.strip() == song.strip():
            print("Correct!")
            points += 3
        else:
            tries -= 1
            print('Incorrect')
            if tries > 0:

                guess = raw_input('Input your guess: ')
                if guess.strip() == song.strip():
                    print('Correct!')
                    points += 1
                else:
                    tries -= 1
                    print('Incorrect')
        print(points)
        time.sleep(3)
        if tries == 0:
            print(points)
            with open("user.csv",'a') as file:
                username=raw_input("Enter username")
                password=raw_input("Enter password")
                points=(points)
                csv_writer = csv.writer(file)
                csv_writer.writerow([username, password, points])
                print("game over")
                with open("user.csv",'r') as file:
                     print(file)



quiz()
```

the username and password for the input y worked yet when I did the quiz it stopped working?
I think it may be an error with the quiz
THE codes work on there own separately
there is nothing in csv file until written to
when pieced together any slight changes made to stop an error

python would generate a new error

Comment: Your code is invalid. I mean, syntactically invalid - this is not something a Python runtime can compile and execute.

Comment: Lots of things wrong here. the line `else print("denied"):` is indented incorrectly and is also a syntax error. You have `return username` outside of a function body. You have `points==row[2]` but you have not yet assigned a value to `points`. And probably a lot more errors.